# Rails3 Arel visits to custom classes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arel, visitor-pattern

I have a custom class, but I want to be able to pass it to Arel and let it resolve its *queryable* part.

```
module Custom
  class Item
    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
      self.name = name
    end
  end
end

custom_item = Custom::Item.new("Bill")
User.where(:name => custom_item)
```

is there anything I can define in custom_item, so it would understand that Arel wants name from it?

Currently I workaround with:

```
module Arel
  module Visitors
    class ToSql
      def visit_Custom_Item o
        "'#{o.name}'"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's not possible now. Let's try to figure out why.

When you try to pass your custom object to the `where` method `User.where(:name => custom_item)` Arel try to call `visit_YOUR_CLASS_NAME` method (https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb#L15) but it fails. Then Arel try to call `visit_`+`object.class.ancestors.find {|klass| respond_to?(DISPATCH[klass], true)}` but it fails again because:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Foo
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x261edc0>
irb(main):004:0> foo.class.ancestors.map {|klass| p klass}
Foo
Object
Kernel
BasicObject
=> [Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

and Arel doesn't have any of this names in this list https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L394:

```
alias :visit_ActiveSupport_Multibyte_Chars :quoted
alias :visit_ActiveSupport_StringInquirer  :quoted
alias :visit_BigDecimal                    :quoted
alias :visit_Class                         :quoted
alias :visit_Date                          :quoted
alias :visit_DateTime                      :quoted
alias :visit_FalseClass                    :quoted
alias :visit_Float                         :quoted
alias :visit_Hash                          :quoted
alias :visit_NilClass                      :quoted
alias :visit_String                        :quoted
alias :visit_Symbol                        :quoted
alias :visit_Time                          :quoted
alias :visit_TrueClass                     :quoted
```

Actually, I don't think it's a very useful feature but I've asked Aaron Patterson about this and if he'll like it I'll try to implement it.

Comment: Imagine you have a Rails 2 app where you have this code passing classes that Arel can not visit to queries in various places, and it works because they have to_s overriden. And it all stops working in Rails 3. I know it is in borderline of Rails/Arel functionality :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to circumvent this problem by defining `to_s` method for my class

```
class CustomItem
  def to_s
    custom_id
  end
end
```

And tricking Arel Visitor to treat my class as Fixnum

```
Arel::Visitors::Visitor::DISPATCH[CustomItem] = 'visit_Fixnum'
```

Worked with Rails 3.2.13.

For string-like value you should probably mimick `String` and use `visit_String`.